# Place bone between another two bones with drivers

Tags: drivers

I would like to place a bone so that it is always in the middle of another two bones and to do it with drivers. My problem is that I seemingly cannot use global translations in pose mode. I would like to find a way to set the position of a bone respecting the global coordinates but whilst being in pose mode. Is that at all possible?

[image]

Problem Example:

[image]

Here we can see that despite that the bone is 2 units on the positive y axis (because there's where I put it in edit mode) the pose mode location still reads (0.0,0.0,0.0).

[image]

In the second image we are still in pose mode and the bone is moved (the move is done in pose mode not in edit mode) by 2 units in the world's  y orientation axis and then the pose mode location reads (0.0,0.0,-2.0). The inconsistency with the axes is due to how each mode's orientation is calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two examples of what should meet your requirements, in the same file.

The first ('Armature.Copy_Location') *doesn't* use drivers, but instead uses Copy_Location constraints:

[image]

note that the copy-location of the second bone has only a 0.5 influence.  It seems to do what's desired.

In the second object ('Armature.Drivers'), I used drivers that instead of using 'Transform Channels' data, instead uses Bone Location Properties.

[image]

[image]

BTW, if you had RMB "copy as new driver" and pasted into the destination bone (to be controlled), you would have gotten this property (my solution) instead!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a driver on all three of the constrained bone's individual axes and query the world-space transforms of the targets from the drivers editor.

Steps for completeness : with your "child" object selected, in *Pose-Mode* right-click the *X Location* axis in the viewport sidebar ( <kbd>N</kbd>), click *Add Driver*, open the drivers editor, navigate to the *Driver* tab then to the *Driver* panel, set the driver type to *averaged value*

Add two input variables set to *Transform Channel*, each targeting one bone's X axis. Make sure the space is set to *World Space*.

Then right-click on the *X Location* axis again, choose *Copy Driver*, right-click on the other axes and choose *Paste Driver*. From there, go back in the drivers editor and change the Xs to Ys and Zs on the two pasted drivers.

[image]

Comment: Thank you  a lot for your input, but that wont work, in pose mode the "location axes" are calculated based on their rest position. So (in pose mode atleast) if a bone isnt moved from its rest position its location is considered as zero! Also any transormation  will start from the rest position.

Comment: @NikosMakris: instead of commenting wrong assumptions, maybe provide a blend file so we can see what you did wrong. Hadriscus answer does work. I just tried it out.

Comment: I tried Hadriscus answer as well and unless I have set something the wrong way in my blender settings (I dont believe I have) then clearly Im missing something important about driver set-up. I edited the question to include the blend file.

Comment: I cannot seem to replicate your solution. It just doesnt work that way in the pose mode. The location of an object on side bar is calculated based on the object's rest position, so if an object has a (rest) position of (2.0,3.0,1.0) based on the world origin then the location on the side bar will read as (0.0,0.0,0.0). If we input a location of (2.0,0.0,0.0) then the bone's new location based on the world transforms will be (5.0,3.0,1.0) despite the fact that it still reads as (2.0,0.0,0.0) on the pose mode location!

Comment: The solution is using World space instead of Local Space, which would *almost* make it meet requirements, but is also using Transform Channels instead of "Property :: pose.bones["Bone..."].location[...]", as I'll show in my next posting here.

Comment: @NikosMakris it works. Make sure to use "World Space" in the driver setup.